# Increase size of ImageView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 and creating an application. I have a register page made up using a constraint layout as follows:

[image: Layout]

This is how I want to look on all devices, however, when testing on my OnePlus 2 the layout becomes the following:

[image: Layout]

As you can see on my device there is a bunch of white-space between the last EditText and the Button.

**Image View XML Properties**

```
    android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnRegister"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPasswordConfirm"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
```

My ImageView is set to a set height which is probably the cause but how do I get it to adjust fir larger screens?

**Folder Structure**

[image]

How do I go about resolving this issue? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's always better to post your complete code. don't worry, no one's gonna steal it !!

Comment: Was just trying to be concise haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```